# Flutter cloud firestore : query document->map->array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My firestore database design]

My db design is above picture. I wanna create a query which returns user where tags are matched. But i didnt any solution to query.

This is my flutter code:

[image]

But it doesnt work. How can i query array of map of document?

Answer (score 1):

The `courses` is an array and not a map so you cannot use the `dot notation` to query. If the `courses` is made a `collection` (or a sub-collection) on it's own then you would be able to query users easily:

```
users -> {userId}
(col)     (doc)

courses -> {courseId}
(col)        (doc)
```

You would have to include a field `userId` in each course document which would be used to identify which user owns that course.

```dart
await firestore.collection("courses").where("tags", arrayContainsAny: tagKeys)
```

This will return all courses where the tags array contains at least 1 item in the `tagKeys` list. If you need exact match i.e. all the tags in `tagKeys` must be present in Firestore document then you would have to restructure the database as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852721/firestore-query-array-contains-all).

---

Fetching all matching documents might not be ideal since you just need user IDs that matches the tags. In that case you can store a field which contains tags from all the courses in a single array field in the user document.

Comment: I need  user info to show course on the list. If i create new collection as "courses" and  search course according to tag list, then do i need to create queries to get users which have that courses?

Comment: @emiled if you want to query users who have a specific course, it'll be best to store an array `course_tags` which will contains tags of all the courses that a user has.